# Store data into database reading from Kafka topic in stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to implement functionality where event messages would be required to consume from Kafka topic and insert into database table (Postgres/H2/Oracle).

Event message would be in json format and it is required to consume continuously. For each message I don't want to insert into database or if I store in the memory and insert in the batch that may cause data lost if any failure occurs. I could use caching DBs e.g. Redis or Hazelcast for storing temp data but don't want to additional infra and cost

Answer (score 0):

> event messages would be required to consume from Kafka topic and insert into database table (Postgres/H2/Oracle).

That's exactly what the JDBC Sink connector is for

> don't want to insert into database or if I store in the memory and insert in the batch that may cause data lost if any failure occurs

The connector does use in memory batches to reduce load on the database writes, so you'll need to clarify why that's a problem